# Android Parcelable vs SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, parcelable

Is it cheaper to send data across Activity using Parcelable or using SQLite? I am using SQLite (through Content Provider) to persist my data. So really I always have access to my data through SQLite. But I am not sure whether I should send data across Activity using Parcelable or should I just grab them each time.

The details. say I have a Village object. So naturally Village is relatively big: it contains Lists of People for instance, which in turn may contain List of Clothes. In onPause of each activity I persist Village to my Content Provider. But sometimes I want to send a Village object from one Activity to another. I have two choices: I can send the dbId to the next activity and then query the URI (and then convert the cursor to a POJO), or I can send a Parcelable of Village. Which is more expensive?

Say Parcelable is cheaper (I don’t know yet). Right now I am struggling to get the Parcelable to work. Is it worth the effort to get Parcelable to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object can be large, then accessing via the `ContentProvider` is the way to go.  Not only will you avoid the marshalling/unmarshalling time & code, but `Parcelable`s are [limited to 1MB](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html).

> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't mean that large. Maybe 0.4MB if that. So continuously querying the db is cheaper than continuously converting to and from Parcel. I should say that each time I query I convert the cursor to a POJO. Does that matter?

Comment: Even at 0.4MB I'd suggest not passing it via a Parcel...  it's 1MB for all transactions in the process, so potentially there may be other messages going around that are taking up lots of that memory..